# Access Denied when calling GetObject

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to access the output of the labeling job that is now stored in s3 bucket I created.
I am doing this via a SageMaker jupyter lab. Why is my access denied to my own bucket?!!!

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3

bucket = "s3://my-bucket"
key = "XXX/output.manifest"

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
```

Comment: Where is this code being run? What credentials are being used to access the object? What permissions have been assigned those credentials. Please Edit your question to include these details.

Comment: I've noticed that all almost your questions got answered yet not a single answer was [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979). Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered.

Comment: Hi John, sorry I just learned how to accept answers. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bucket should be:

```
bucket = "my-bucket"
```

not:

```
bucket = "s3://my-bucket"
```